# Альтернатива onHashChange в ie7 ?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Есть ли альтернатива onHashChange в ie7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть вам понравиться этот [jquery плагин](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/), работает в ие7 и не надо искать альтервнатив

Comment: Его и использовал ,работает П-Р-Е-К-Р-А-С-Н-О )

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите еще на [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js). Это не только hashchange (для IE6+), но еще и HTML5 history API, и все в достаточно удобной обертке.

Comment: Интересная штучка с ХТМЛ5 надо глянуть)

Answer (score 0):

Есть интересная [идейка](http://www.zachleat.com/web/onhashchange-without-setinterval/), без использования setInterval или setTimeout.
Ну, на крайняк, можете навесить событие на элементы, меняющие хэш.

Answer (score -1):

Да, проверять раз в 50мс **steInterval()** изменился ли он location.hash или нет.