# Навигация ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Есть проект одностраничный, все подгружается через ajax. Как сделать, чтоб адрес был

```
http://mysite.com/'нужная страница'
```

Чтоб всегда шла загрузка index.php и, исходя из конца адреса, строилась страница ajax?

Answer (score 3):

Наверно, лучше будет использовать HTML 5 History API. Пройдите по [этой ссылке](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API), там после мануала на английском будет мануал на русском, а также [демо 
от автора](http://history.spb-piksel.ru/), где можно скачать исходники сайта.

P.S. Когда я разбирался, с этим делом мне этот мануал очень помог. Удачи ;)

Comment: а как сделать чтоб всегда грузился index.php

Comment: в каком смысле грузился? я вот что то не понимаю, что вы хотите)

Comment: сайт состаит из одной страници а все остально подгружаеться ajax и изменяеться url надо чтоб эти url работали получаеться надо чтоб всегда загружался index.php а по url строился сайт javascript

Comment: так в чем проблема?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/163458/jquery-эмуляция-несуществующих-страниц-с-помощью-ajax-по-url

Comment: вам тут все дали, ссылки и описания как это реализовать.

Comment: если я вас правильно понял, вам нужно чтобы при переходе на ссылки страниц, содержимое которых подгружается js, отображались именно эти страницы?
Если это так то еще раз взгляните на исходный код демо сайта(архив: http://code.spb-piksel.ru/site_history.zip), и думаю что все вопросы отпадут))

Дерзайте ;)

Comment: [По ссылке](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API), которую вам дал @cho0pa в ответе, внизу страницы, есть мануал на русском с примерами. Разобраться даже новичку легко.

Answer (score 2):

Копайте в направлении [history Hash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/31309/javascript-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-onhashchange-%D0%B2-ie7?).

В вк так:

```
var setLoc = function (loc) {
    //curLoc = fixEncode(loc.replace(/#(\/|!)?/, ''));
    curLoc = fixEncode(loc);
    var l = (location.toString().match(/#(.*)/) || {})[1] || '';
    if (!l && vk.al > 1) {
        l = (location.pathname || '') + (location.search || '');
    }
    l = fixEncode(l);
    if (l.replace(/^(\/|!)/, '') != curLoc) {
        if (vk.al == 3) {
            try {
                history.pushState({}, '', '/' + curLoc);
                return;
            } catch (e) {}
        }
        window.chHashFlag = true;
        location.hash = '#' + vk.navPrefix + curLoc;
        if (withFrame && getLoc() != curLoc) {
            setFrameContent(curLoc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо   )))

Comment: Плагинчик хороший, но уже устарел.